# Best strategy for Foursquare venue/search caching

Tags: caching, foursquare

We are looking to use Foursquare as the location database for our application. Their API states that an application can make up to 5,000 userless requests per hour to venues/* endpoints. In order to help reduce the amount of requests, they recommend that you utilize caching to avoid making repetitive calls to the Foursquare API when different users are requesting the same information.

For our application, we are looking to use the venues/search endpoint to get checkin data around a location. What is the best way to go about caching this data to allow for the least amount of calls to the Foursquare API?

The current idea we have is to cache km by km “boxes” that represent an area on the earth. When a user requests nearby venues, we would make a call from the center point location of the box they are currently in to Foursquare, and cache the results for that box. Now when another user comes along, if they are too in that box we can return the results that we had cached for that box that are closest to the user. If a user is close to the edge of a box, we would return the close results from the box they are currently in, as well as the close results in the adjacent box.

Is this a good way to go about things to limit the requests? We fear this technique may use way too much memory.  How do you go about it in your applications? Any insights would be great, thanks!

Comment: Did you approach work out? I was thinking about storing lat/lng of the original request. If a new request is nearby the lat/lng combination, say 20 meters, the cached result is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a good strategy for caching venue searches. However, just to be super clear on Foursquare [policies](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/ratelimits), they state that "Server-side caching of venue **details** is generally required for apps requesting an increase." We don't make caching of search results an explicit requirement before granting rate limit increases, only calls to [venue details](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues).